# Is is possible to take the derivative like this?

Tags: derivatives, economics

I am a graduate student in the economics department. I should write a dissertation. I got stuck in an equation. There is an equation like this ($\ln P = \ln K + \ln W - \ln Q$). All the variables have a unique meaning. But the K variable is the most important. I want to say that the change rate of K is 0. Is it possible to say that to illustrate the rate of the difference all the variables' we should take derivatives like this ($dP/P = dK/K + dW/W - dQ/Q$). If so I can say $dK/K = 0$.

edit:
P: Price
K: Fixed mark-up rate
C: Unit labor costs
P = K.C
Unit labor cost is W/C and W is the hourly wage of labor
C = W/Q
So P = K.(W/Q)
I want to illustrate the impact of the dependent variables on the independent variable. But the mark-up rate is unchangeable. All the rest variables are time-dependent. I guess I should differentiate the equation with respect to time. Is my way true?

Comment: There is not enough context here to answer your question. Do the variables $P$, $K$, $W$ and $Q$ depend on time? On each other in any way other than the stated equation? What does "want to say the rate of change of $K$ is $0$"
mean? Please [edit] the question to give us a lot more context - don't try to clarify in a comment.

Comment: Using the exponential function $e^x$ to both sides you'll get $P=\frac{KW}Q$.

Comment: "I should write a dissertation." ... it is really hard, sometimes, to not bite the newcomers. You are not even able to write down proportional equations in a readable way, making sure all variables are covered.

Answer (score 0):

If $K,W,Q$ are univariate functions of time, with $P$ determined by $K,W,Q$ , then indeed one may differentiate w.r.t time:

$$\dot P/P=\dot K/K+\dot W/W-\dot Q/Q$$

and what you wrote is just differential notation for the above.